# How to get single field array value and insert or update in the node.js

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get products value and want to insert in item table. But I don't have an idea. How to get this object value.
I got below result in console.

I got other value using this method: **`req.body.order_date`**

[image]

Comment: `obj['product[]']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Lodash** package to get the value for specific key using javascipt. Here, _get is the method of Lodash packet which will take first argument as object and second argument as key name.

For more details, you can check [LODASH Documentation](https://lodash.com/)

This is one pretty clean solution for your problem:

```js
var obj ={ 
'product[]' : ["product1","product2"]
};

console.log(_.get(obj, ['product[]']))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js'></script>
```